# JQuery autocomplete is not working in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have used jquery autocomplete to fetch organization list. If list size is greater than 40,50 records then on internet explorer it is not showing any data but on firefox and chrome proper list data is shown.
Why on IE it is not showing data?

Comment: If you are using windows8 OS, then you might get some help from here [http://www.pcandtablet.com/windows-8-browsers/584/solved-microsoft-internet-explorer-10-autocomplete-does-not-work-in-windows-8-a.html]

Comment: @D.T. nope using windows 7 OS